# How to dynamically add buttons in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am creating one dynamic table for that am getting data from controller, previously I was using `jquery ajax` to load table content

```
success: function (response) {
for (var i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {

                    var table = '<tr  id="' + List[i].Id + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td id="name' + i + '">' + List[i].name + '</td><td><i class="edit fa fa-pencil-square-o" id="edit' + i + '"></i><i class="update fa fa-floppy-o" id="update' + i + '"></i><i class="editCancel fa fa-times" id="editCancel' + i + '" ></i></td><tr>';
                    $('#content').append(table);
                    editUpdate();
                }
}
```

Now the same thing I trying using angular

```
<script>
    var app=angular
                .module("intranet_App", [])
                .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                    $http.post("/Admin/getRolesList")
                    .then(function (response) {                     
                        $scope.roleList = response.data;
                      });
                })
</script>
```

I am getting table data ,but how to add buttons dynamically along with that(for each row i need to add buttons in action column)table data using angular?

HTML:

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="mydata" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                    <thead class="colorBlue">
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.No</th>
                            <th>Role Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="">
                        <tr ng-repeat="x in roleList | filter:searchText">
                            <td>{{x.Id}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: You can add  this element to get button in your 3rd column  <td><button>Add</button></td>

Answer (score 1):

Row will be created dynamically based on roleList by using `ng-repeat`. If you add new column `td` with button then they will be added for every row.

```
<tbody id="">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in roleList | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{x.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td><button></button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Is it possible to initialize like `i=0` and to use iteration of `i` in every button.

Comment: you can use $index for iteration https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="mydata" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <thead class="colorBlue">
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Role Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="">
        <tr ng-repeat="x in roleList | filter:searchText">
            <td>{{x.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <i class="edit fa fa-pencil-square-o" id="edit{{x.Id}}"></i>
                <i class="update fa fa-floppy-o" id="update{{x.Id}}"></i>
                <i class="editCancel fa fa-times" id="editCancel{{x.Id}}" ></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then to have click events on them, you can do `ng-click`s on them, for example:

```
<td>
    <i class="edit fa fa-pencil-square-o" id="edit{{x.Id}}" ng-click="edit(x.Id)"></i>
    <i class="update fa fa-floppy-o" id="update{{x.Id}}" ng-click="update(x.Id)"></i>
    <i class="editCancel fa fa-times" id="editCancel{{x.Id}}" ng-click="cancel(x.Id)"></i>
</td>
```

Comment: can you please check here `edit(x.Id)`...is this correct syntax?

Comment: It is, because inside `ng-click` it uses plain JavaScript, so you can directly use the `x` variable from the `ng-repeat` and access its properties, so this will call a function `edit` with whatever value `x.Id` has. Just make sure that there is a function called edit in the scope